# Trying to remove ads in Gmail with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm experimenting with a Chrome extension that will remove the ads displayed in the right-hand pane in Gmail and instead put the information I want there.  (I haven't decided exactly what to put there yet; vacillating between several ideas, including external content and/or attachments.)

The ads are (usually) contained in a `<div class="oM"></div>` element.  But I can't seem to select that either in my extension or in the console.

I've tested my `manifest.json` settings by writing an extension that added a superfluous div to the top of the page, and that worked fine -- I just created a new element and

```
document.body.parentElement.insertBefore(new_el, document.body);
```

However, what I'm trying to do now is just rip out the ads and put in some dummy text, or just put the text above the ads.  This is the main function called in my content_script.js file.

```
function modifyPage(txt) {

    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('oM')[0];

    container.innerHTML = txt;

}


function modifyPage(txt) {
    var insert = document.createElement('div');
    insert.innerText = txt;

    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('oM')[0];

    document.body.parentElement.insertBefore(insert, container);

}
```

I've even tried to jQuery:

```
function modifyPage(txt) {
    $('.oM').html(txt);

}
```

Also, trying to retrieve the `<div class="oM">` using the Chrome console returns nothing -- even though I can see it right there in the source.

Comment: -1, it's because of folks like you that make free products difficult to exist.  If you don't like the ads, pay for it.

Comment: @Brad, I appreciate your sentiment -- how about instead of downvoting my question (unrelated to its merits and to the mission of StackOverflow), you suggest some guidance on how to achieve my goal without removing the ads?  That way you get to influence me, help Google, and not sound like a jerk.  For instance, you can see that I've also tried to insert my own information above, rather than replacing the ads.

Comment: I'm leaving my downvote, as I believe what you are doing is against the ToS, and questions like this damage the community here at Stack Overflow. If someone takes issue with this determination, they are welcome to upvote or discuss it on meta and post a link. I don't typically downvote questions I disagree with, but I don't hesitate to do so when someone is trying to do something illegal or against the ToS for the product in question. I suggest you display your content elsewhere, outside of the Gmail interface. Be careful, as attempting to "frame" Gmail is also against the ToS.

Comment: Don't you think that it's within the spirit of experimentation encourage by posts like http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2007/10/code-changes-to-prepare-gmail-for.html?  I guess I didn't make it clear in the post, but this exercise was for learning purposes -- a test to see if I could replicate what Rapportive had accomplished (which uses the Greasemonkey Gmail API, I think).  I think that modifying and playing with web code is one of the great things about the web and a great way to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Set a delay on the execution of your jquery selector. The Google Tubes are a bit more complicated than using static div classes on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than remove the ads with JS, just hide them with CSS:

```
.oM {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `AdBlock` + `Chrome add-in(or extension)`.
It works very well it's a donation-ware, I'm guessing the author use jquery `{display:none }` to `hide` or `remove` the ads with a custom filter lists.